# Do feature fixes need to be local only?

Tags: git, branching, gitflow

From [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) blog post describing the git-flow model, it seems that feature branches have to remain local to the user working on them and are actually deleted right before pushing to `origin`.

This kind of makes sense, but what if other people want to checkout my feature branch to help me out for example? Should I push my branch only then? Should I not? If so why?

Comment: @DocBrown Yes, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the original gitflow specification, there is no requirement that features be local only, only that they [SHOULD NOT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) be pushed to origin:

> Feature branches typically exist in developer repos only, not in *origin*.

However, it's not a hard requirement. The gitflow API supports [publishing and tracking features](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments#git-flow-feature-publish-name) on origin:

> ```
> git flow feature publish <name>
> ```
>
> Start sharing feature `<name>` on `$ORIGIN`
>
> ```
> git flow feature track <name>
> ```
>
> Start tracking feature `<name>` that is shared on `$ORIGIN`

It was not part of the original specification, but was silently added in [gitflow 0.2](http://nvie.com/posts/an-upgrade-of-gitflow/) when it was [refactored to be a git subcommand](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/commit/00ccea60aef8174caf0dc64c2fad36a28ecd7064).